# How to draw an html table with diagonal lines and diagonal text?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How I can draw this kind of table using html5 and css3 any suggestion?

[image: Example]

I tried this I think that is too complicated: [Diagonal Lines and Diagonal Texts](http://jsfiddle.net/eduardoustarez/us3vbqju/)

I am using css3 styles and svg html5 tag,
Is there other way that I could make this kind of html-table ?

```
<div style='width: 300px; height: 100px; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;'>
<div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0); position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
    <div style='margin-left:-40px; margin-top:25px; width: 80px; height: 30px; font-size:19px; background-color: yellow; -ms-transform: rotate(315deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(315deg);'>DATO3</div>
</div>
<div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0); position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
    <div style='margin-left:-45px; margin-top:25px; width: 80px; height: 30px; font-size:19px; background-color: yellow; -ms-transform: rotate(315deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(315deg);'>DATO2</div>
</div>
    <div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0px solid black; position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
    <div style='margin-left:-40px; margin-top:25px; width: 80px; height: 30px; background-color: white; -ms-transform: rotate(315deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(315deg);'></div>
</div>
    </div>
<div style='width: 300px; height: 100px; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;'>
<div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top: 0px solid black; position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
</div>
    <div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0); position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0); position: relative;'>
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use an actual `<table>`...

Comment: How I can do diagonal lines in a <table>? Do you have an example?

Comment: How is [this for a basic concept?](http://jsbin.com/xujok/1/edit)

Comment: It works for me, Thank you so much. This css style works on IE9 or later, doesn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main building blocks are:

- A nicely marked up `<table>`
- A pseudo element border with skew to get the basic shape
- A rotate on the span that contains the header text.

The concept is pretty basic, the pseudo elements and spans are positioned using `position: absolute` and they are positioned relative to their parent `<th>` headers which have `position: relative`

[Here is the example!](http://jsbin.com/duduwa/1/edit)

Here is what it looks like in Chrome / Firefox / IE10+. IE 8 - 9 should work with their proprietary filters.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the HTML / CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #FFF;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    position: relative;
}

/* Very top border */
 table:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 240px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Far right headers top border (it's outside the table) */
 table:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    width: 101px;
    right: -101px;
    top: 0;
}

/* 
     - Apply header background/font colour 
     - Set base z-index for IE 9 - 10
*/
 thead, th:before {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* min-width and max-width together act like a width */
 th {
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

/* Pseudo element borders */
 th:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Apply the right border only to the last pseudo element */
 thead th:last-child:before {
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
}

/* Apply the top border only to the first rows cells */
 tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
}

/* 
     - Rotate and position headings
     - Padding centers the text vertically and does the job of height
     - z-index ensures that the text appears over the background color in IE 9 - 10
*/
 th span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    right: -70px;
    bottom: 29px;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0.75em 0 1.85em;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* Create first two th styles */
 th:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(2) {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: none;
}
th:nth-child(1):before, th:nth-child(2):before {
    display: none;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
tfoot {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th><span>Three</span></th>
            <th><span>Four</span></th>
            <th><span>Five</span></th>
            <th><span>Six</span></th>
            <th><span>Seven</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I tested on [Cross Browser Testing](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/), I will try to use IE filters.

Comment: @EduardoUstarez - Please see my updated answer, it contains many improvements and works cross-browser IE10+ / Firefox / Chrome. I'm quite happy with the result so far :)

Comment: Yes, I tested. I appreciate your feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask you something?. how to I can change the color of the cell three and five.

Comment: @EduardoUstarez - I just tested it (was on my mobile before). Just use `th:nth-child(3):before, th:nth-child(5):before { background:#000; }` at the bottom of your tables CSS. [Read more about nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)